# c++ std set insert not "working"

Tags: c++, set

I'm having some problems with std set. I know that it does not allows you to insert repeated elements and (I think that) my code is not trying to insert repeated elements. But it seems like the set is not inserting both elements. What is the problem? Is the collection considering both elements equal? Why?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct sam{
    double a,b, tam;
    sam(){

    }
    sam(double a1, double b1){
        a = a1;
        b = b1;
        tam = b - a;
    }
    bool operator<(const sam &p) const{
        return tam > p.tam;
    }

};
set<sam> ssw;

int main(void){

    ssw.insert(sam(0,2));
    ssw.insert(sam(4,6));
    cout<<ssw.size()<<"\n"; // prints "1"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sam(0, 2)` is equivalent to `sam(4, 6)` according to your comparison.

Comment: Why? How can I fix it? Or maybe should I use priority_queue?

Comment: Why? Because you wrote your comparison this way. How to fix it? That rather depends on what you are trying to achieve, which was never adequately explained.

Comment: Igor is right. Also std::set::insert will just quietly reject the insertion without causing any real problems. It just won't insert multiple values that are equal.

Comment: Your comparison compares the *difference* in values. The *difference* is `2` in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `std::set`

> In imprecise terms, two objects a and b are considered equivalent (not
>   unique) if neither compares less than the other: !comp(a, b) &&
>   !comp(b, a)

In your case `bool operator<` not satisfy the above condition hence set treats them not `unique`.

Answer (score 3):

For both objects, the value of `tam` is 2.0. Since the `operator<` function works with that value, the two objects are considered to be equal.

BTW, using a floating point number to compare two objects is not a good idea. You can get unexpected results due to the imprecise nature of how floating points are represented.

Answer (score 2):

Currently your comparator returns same values for both the inserts. Hence, only one item is successfully inserted. The other is just a duplicate, and is hence, ignored.

Maybe you meant this:

```
bool operator<(const sam &p) const{
        return ( (a > p.a) || (b > p.b) || (tam > p.tam) );
    }
```